# How can I put a HTML code in Outlook 2010?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2010

How can I put a HTML code in outlook 2010?
The code is:

```
<p style="color:red;">Hello</p>
```

How can I put that in the message using Outlook 2010?

Answer (score 5):

Might need to find a different email client/editor if you want to send HTML tags in your email:  http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/i-can-t-use-html-tags-in-html-e-mail-messages-HA010199144.aspx

> Microsoft Office Outlook 2007 uses an
>   e-mail message editor based on
>   Microsoft Office Word 2007. Office
>   Outlook 2007 offers a WYSIWYG (what
>   you see is what you get) editing
>   environment. The message that you
>   compose is converted to HTML format
>   for sending.
>
> Office Outlook 2007 is not designed
>   for you to directly enter or view HTML
>   tags when composing an e-mail message.

Comment: Does this still apply to later versions of Outlook?

Answer (score 4):

You need to install HTML Code Editor for Outlook, which is Outlook add-in to allow you edit native HTML directly on Outlook.

http://outlookhtmleditor.codeplex.com/

You can download a installer on download tab. It'll allow you to import HTML file or edit HTML source code of your e-mail.

Comment: This still works with Outlook 2016!

Comment: Here is an updated link, as the original page seems to be gone:
https://web.archive.org/web/20211017134457/https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=outlookhtmleditor