# microsoft outlook 2010 - how use html source code as a message?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, html, microsoft-office-2010

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I put a HTML code in Outlook 2010?](https://superuser.com/questions/213825/how-can-i-put-a-html-code-in-outlook-2010)

hi my dear friends :

is it possible to use html codes in microsoft office 2010 (Outlook) for sending emails?

thansk in future advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might need to find a different email client/editor if you want to send HTML tags in your email:  http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/i-can-t-use-html-tags-in-html-e-mail-messages-HA010199144.aspx

> Microsoft Office Outlook 2007 uses an
>   e-mail message editor based on
>   Microsoft Office Word 2007. Office
>   Outlook 2007 offers a WYSIWYG (what
>   you see is what you get) editing
>   environment. The message that you
>   compose is converted to HTML format
>   for sending.
>
> Office Outlook 2007 is not designed
>   for you to directly enter or view HTML
>   tags when composing an e-mail message.